# chrome extension get cookies doesnt return all cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension which gets cookie from my domain and process it. But the problem here is that `chrome.cookies.getAll(domain:"mydomain")` doesnt return the all the cookies. for example i am getting cookies of firebase.google.com but its retuning only one cookie but when i go to firebase.google.com i could many cookie items

Manifest permission i used

```
"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "cookies",
        "https://*/*",
        "contextMenus",
        "storage",
        "webNavigation"
    ],
```

backgroundjs:

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({domain:""firebase.google.com"},function(cookie){
        console.log(cookie);
});
```

What i could see in console contains only one cookie value. But when i go to url firebase.google.com i could see more number of cookies in developer tools.
[image: developer tools values][image: console.log values]
How could i get all the cookie values in getAll function?

Comment: Those other cookies are for different domains as you can see in devtools. To replicate the same behavior see [Chrome extension get all tab cookies](//stackoverflow.com/a/50099635)

Comment: I want to access my-domain cookies from the background with irrespective to the current domain? how to do that? @wOxxOm

Comment: chrome.cookies API returns exactly what you tell it. Devools shows extra cookies. These are different things. If you want to do what devtools does then you'll need to enumerate all the extra domains yourself explicitly.